# How to give an initial solution to a LP problem in IBM CPLEX ILOG

Tags: optimization, cplex, timetable

What is the correct parameter to give an initial solution to a LP problem in IBM ILOG CPLEX using OPL.

I'm modelling a large scale school timetabling problem and as a way of reducing the total solution time, i'd like to begin the process with an initial solution, i.e last year's timetable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [IloOplCplexVectors](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/IloOplCplexVectors.html) for that purpose. The example shipped in `opl/examples/opl/warmstart/warmstart.mod` does exactly what you have in mind. It should help to get you going.